# How to change the data type from integer to float after applying a function in python

Tags: python

my question is when I was trying to run the codes below:

```
gradePF=gradesAll.groupby('clid').apply(lambda x:
    (sum(x['PF'] == 0) / sum(x['PF'] == 1))
).reset_index()
```

as the data in PF is actually integer so the result is still integer. I want to specify the result as a 2-digit float I tried Decimal but it seemed not working. Any ideas? Thx!

update:

Let me put it in this way. for a very simple example,
`m=sum([1,2,3])/sum([2,3])` I want the result as 1.2 but it prints out 1. I don't need the format in `print` function but the `m` variable itself has a value of 1.2. Thx!

Comment: At two places in your code you sum the result of a comparison: `sum(x['PF']==0)`. This should give the error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`

Comment: It may work for some input, but that would be due to that code never executing.

Comment: @MYjx if that code executed, it would resolve to `(sum(True) / sum(False))` (the booleans may vary. You cannot `sum` a boolean, because it is not iterable (as @andrewjohnson points out). That code snippet cannot execute.

Comment: It will work if you wrap it in brackets like so `sum([x['PF']==0])`. True and False both have integer representations that will be used in the event this code executes.

Comment: i see but for me I only want to count how many are true and how many are false after I add `[]` as @lanAuid suggested, the codes actually crashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using python 2. This does integer division by default;

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug  3 2014, 12:51:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032)] on freebsd10
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 1/3
0
>>> 4/2
2
>>> 5/2
2
>>> m=sum([1,2,3])/sum([2,3])
>>> m
1
```

You can either explicitly convert to float;

```
>>> 2/float(3)
0.6666666666666666
```

Or use the following in the top of your module;

```
from __future__ import division
```

Which changes the behaviour of the interpreter and makes it compatible with Python 3 (in this aspect);

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug  3 2014, 12:51:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032)] on freebsd10
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/2
0.5
>>> 1/3
0.3333333333333333
>>> 4/2
2.0
>>> m=sum([1,2,3])/sum([2,3])
>>> m
1.2
```

Comment: another thing is do you know how to close this division? it messed up the results afterwards..@RolandSmith

Comment: @MYjx What do you mean by "close"? I do not understand.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I figured out later it is not because of this line that messed up my results. But I am still a little bit curious about how this module might be able to specify the number of digits of the float? thx! @RolandSmith

Comment: Python uses [double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) binary [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) numbers internally. That can give you approximately a maximum of 16 decimal digits (see the 1/3 above). If you want to *print* a float, you can use e.g. `str.format` to decide how the number should look like.